# How to run method when a div re-init - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I try

```
<div v-if="isRun" v-html="myMethod"></div>
<div v-else v-html="myMethod2"></div>

computed: {
  myMethod: function() {
    alert('1');
  },
  myMethod2: function() {
    alert('2');
  },
}
```

and `isRun` variable's change dynamic (switch by user) and i want `myMethod` and `myMethod2` re-run when `div` re-init.

But I try with `v-html` it only run first time.

How to do that. thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you are strictly want to use this methods, [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) watch their dependencies for changes before they get updated, from the docs

> You can data-bind to computed properties in templates just like a normal property. Vue is aware that vm.reversedMessage depends on vm.message, so it will update any bindings that depend on vm.reversedMessage when vm.message changes. And the best part is that we’ve created this dependency relationship declaratively: the computed getter function has no side effects, which makes it easier to test and understand.

Here is a simple hack for your needs, there is better ways for this approach

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data:{
    isRun: true,
  },
  computed: {
    myMethod: function() {
        this.isRun == this.isRun // it doesn't really depend on this.isRun but vue thinks it does
        alert('1');
    },
    myMethod2: function() {
        this.isRun == this.isRun
      alert('2');
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="isRun" v-html="myMethod"></div>
  <div v-else v-html="myMethod2"></div>
  
  
  <button @click="isRun = !isRun">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, it seem to working but if you have any other right way, can you share that.

Comment: i think this way better [https://jsfiddle.net/3esn1edp/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/3esn1edp/2/)

Comment: But in real, i have many condition (in this example i only wirte one like isRun), and maybe we must be using trick `this.isRun == this.isRun` ?. If I have many condition then that .... . Maybe has a right way

Comment: I think it is better to use the last example and check on all your condition and decide what to show in `toggleRun` method, and if you have to much content in your template maybe consider [components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) ?